# How do I get the Polynomial Interpolation coefficients using gsl_interp?

Tags: c++, interpolation, gsl

So I have the code below. It perfectly calculates all the y-points of the polynomial (and prints them to plot with gnuplot), but how do i get the resulting polynomial (1-x² in this case)?

```
void twoDegreePoly() {
    int n = 3;
    double x[n],y[n];
    printf ("#m=0,S=16\n");
    for (int i=0; i<n ;i++) {
        x[i] = ((double)2*i)/2 -1;
        y[i] = f(x[i]);
        printf ("%g %g\n", x[i], y[i]);
    }
    printf ("#m=1,S=0\n");

    gsl_interp_accel *acc = gsl_interp_accel_alloc ();
    const gsl_interp_type *t = gsl_interp_polynomial;
    gsl_interp* poly = gsl_interp_alloc(t,n);
    gsl_interp_init (poly, x, y,n);
    for (double xi=x[0]; xi<x[n-1]; xi+= 0.01) {
        double yi = gsl_interp_eval (poly, x, y, xi, acc);
        printf ("%g %g\n", xi, yi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick scan over the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Interpolation.html#Interpolation), it doesn't seem that such a feature is available in the GSL. This could be caused by two reasons: first, getting polynomial coeffcients is special to this interpolation method doesn't fit well into the general design (which can handle arbitrary functions). Second, citing Numerical Recipes:

> Please be certain, however, that the coefficients are what you need. Generally, the coefficients of the interpolating polynomial can be determined much less accurately than its value at a desired abscissa. Therefire, it is not a good idea to determine the coefficients only for use in calculating interpolating values. Values thus calculated will not pass exactly through the tabulated points, for example, ...

The reason for this is that in principle, calculating the coefficients involves solving a linear system with a Vandermonde matrix, which is highly ill-conditioned.

Still, Numerical Recipes gives a routine `polcoe` by which you can obtain the interpolating polynomial. You can find it in chapter 3.5. in the [free second edition](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html).

Comment: copyright problem: you can't publish NR code in tho site

Comment: This code is available in the free second edition of Numerical Recipes, see page 121 [here](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html). I've just changed the C-arrays into vectors.

Comment: the fact that the book is available on the official website does not change the copyrights restriction on publishing the code. You must contact the authors.

Comment: Isn't that a bit too pedantic? I mean, whether you get the code directly here under mention of its origin, or by another click is practically the same. But if you insist, give me some hard facts and I'll delete it from the post (with which it would still be available in the revision history).

Comment: No, it isn't. Copyrights is the reason why Numerical Recipes sucks and should be boycotted. Take a look at this website (http://mingus.as.arizona.edu/~bjw/software/boycottnr.html). Publishing copyrighted code is against the rules of this website. You could just create a link to NR website and that would be ok. I flagged this answer.

Comment: ok, I've removed the code from the answer and replaced it by the link.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar with the Akima's interpolation.
First, define the state as GSL do:

```
typedef struct
{
  double *b;
  double *c;
  double *d;
  double *_m;
}akima_state_t;
```

Then, create the interpolant

```
spline = gsl_spline_alloc (gsl_interp_akima, M_size);
gsl_spline_init (spline, x, y, M_size);
```

and after that, you can do :

```
const akima_state_t *state = (const akima_state_t *) ( spline -> interp -> state);
  double _b,_c,_d;
  for (int i = 0; i < M_size; i++)
  {
    _b = state->b[i];
    _c = state->c[i];
    _d = state->d[i];
    std::cout << "(x>"<<x[i]<<")*(x<"<<x[i+1]<<")*("<<y[i]<< "+ (x-"<< x[i]<<")*("<<_b<<"+(x-"<< x[i]<<")*("<<_c<<"+"<<_d<<"*(x-"<<x[i]<<")))) + ";
  }
```

I do not have tried with a polynomial interpolation, but here the state struct for polynomial, it should be a good starting point.

```
typedef struct
{
  double *d;
  double *coeff;
  double *work;
}
polynomial_state_t;
```